# multiple files into single payload

Tags: mule

My requirement is I'm querying salesforce files object and getting all files under the same record. 1. I need to merge all files if the parent id is same.

What I done is?

Querying the all files object `where parentId= '#[flowVars.ParentId]'.`

after query I'm getting

> unknown number of files(1 to 5).

How Do I process this and merge into one payload.

Also this finished another `ParentId` will come with files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataweave to merge your payload.

Use flatten operator. In dataweave try,

```
flatten (payload filter (parentId == 'id'))
```